# 'Twice' v. 'twice over'

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

What is the difference between, for example, 'twice' and 'twice over'. "Used to say how many times the same thing happens" — it's how Longman [defines](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/twice-over-three-times-over-etc) it. I see no difference with simply 'twice'.

Comment: We add 'over' if we wish to particularly emphasise that something has happened more than once,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe an example will explain better. Look:

Let's assume that the following situation happens in a casino.

Man: "Please, spin the dice twice".
Woman: "Ok, sir. Done".
Man: "Oh my God. I lost again! Please, spin the dice twice over".

The man only asked the woman to spin twice over after asking some seconds before to draft twice.

Summing up, the **over** is used to emphasize that something already happened and will happen again.